# Jquery Geocoding Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, performance, functional-programming

The rules for this script are simple:

- If geocode is hit, then just geocode
- If geocode and submit is hit, then geocode and then submit
- If an autosuggest link is hit, then geocode instantly
- In this case, do not re-geocode later when the button is hit

This is my code, based on help and advice from here:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/Jfdbz/14/

```
$(function () {
    var lastQuery = null,
        lastResult = null, // new!
        autocomplete,
        processLocation = function (callback) { // accept a callback argument
            var input = $("#loc"),
                lat = $("#lat"),
                long = $("#lng");
            var query = $.trim(input.val()),
                geocoder;
            // if query is empty or the same as last time...
            if (!query || query === lastQuery) {
                if (callback) {
                    callback(lastResult); // send the same result as before
                }
                return; // and stop here
            }

            lastQuery = query; // store for next time

            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({
                address: query
            }, function (results, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    lat.val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                    long.val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                    lastResult = true; // success!
                } else {
                    alert("Sorry - We couldn't find this location. Please try an alternative");
                    lastResult = false; // failure!
                }
                if (callback) {
                    callback(lastResult); // send the result back
                }
            });
        },
        ctryiso = $("#ctry").val(),
        options = {
            types: ["geocode"]
        };

    if (ctryiso !== '') {
        options.componentRestrictions = {
            'country': ctryiso
        };
    }
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#loc")[0], options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', processLocation);

    $('#search').click(function (e) {
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the submission

        processLocation(function (success) {
            if (success) { // if the geocoding succeeded, submit the form
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    });

    $('#geosearch').click(function (e) {
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the submission
        processLocation();
    });
});
```

I think I have reached the point where it works correctly, and I can't seem to make it any more structured, any more readable, any more efficient or compact. However, I am new to javascript and I would be really open to hear if anyone feels that they can improve on this.

I must admit I a bit pedantic and get a lot of satisfaction out of the refining process!

EDIT: I pasted the code wrong - fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few things in no particular order:

- Don't use `long` as a variable name. It's a reserved word in Javascript and can cause confusion.
- If you're going to disable the country input in your form, you should probably just put the US keyword straight in your code. That is if you don't intend on enabling it.
- You set `ctryiso = $("#ctry").val()` and then test `ctryiso !== ''`. Since you hard coded the country value in, that will always be true. Therefore, unnecessary test.
- You don't need to initialize your `lastQuery` and `lastResult` to null. Any falsy value will do just fine in JS, including `undefined`.
- If you look at the jQuery source code you'll see that the `.click()` simply calls another method and passes the values on. You can save a few function calls if you just call that other method directly.

Like so:

```
$('#search').click(function (e) {
    //Do stuff
}

//Do this one instead
$('#search').on('click', function (e) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

The 'click' can be replaced with any event of you're choosing. This gives you enormous power and control when setting up custom events.